# selenium python: open default profile in opera

Tags: python, selenium

How do I open the default profile in Opera? 
I mean the same profile as when I open the stand along Opera. 
This code just opens up with a new profile:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
os.environ["SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR"] = '/home/brian/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar'
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.OPERA
capabilities['opera.profile'] = ''  
browser = webdriver.Opera(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you set the profile the same way you do with Chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
opera_profile = 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\roaming\Opera software\\Opera Stable'  # relevant for Windows 7 and above
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + opera_profile)
opera_driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=<path_to_operadriver>, opera_options=options)
```